# How can I code a textarea similar to Stackoverflow, FB, or OKC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, dhtml

How does stackoverflow implement the "comments" section of this site?  I'd like to create something similar to a FB Wall or okcupid.com profile edit.

My goal is to create a wiki of sorts that has editable regions like each of these sites.  It's important that I can associate the user's cookie with the edit on the serverside so I can maintain tracking.

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Your question is too general.. specify exacly what you want to achive!

Answer (score 1):

Take the [WebDeveloper Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) in Firefox. Select Information > View JavaScript. It's all there, just add a little AJAX for the updates. Not sure if this practice is allowed though, I believe the sources of SO are copyrighted.

The MarkDown, of course, is partially stripped, but you can simplify this part by simply allowing all MarkDown and downloading one of the open source parsers.